# how display current_user/invited_by user email display of devise invitable invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, devise-invitable

I use my own mailer instead of having devise email things for me, as per [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Use-custom-mailer) documentation.

Here is how I do it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :raw_invitation_token
end

class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def create
    @from    = params[:from]
    @subject = params[:invite_subject]
    @content = params[:invite_content]

    @user = User.invite!(params[:user], current_user) do |u|
      u.skip_invitation = true
    end


    email = NotificationMailer.invite_message(@user, @from, @subject, @content)
  end
end

class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def invite_message(user, venue, from, subject, content)
    @user = user
    @token = user.raw_invitation_token
    invitation_link = accept_user_invitation_url(:invitation_token => @token)

    mail(:from => from, :bcc => from, :to => @user.email, :subject => subject) do |format|
      content = content.gsub '{{first_name}}', user.first_name
      content = content.gsub '{{last_name}}', user.first_name
      content = content.gsub '{{full_name}}', user.full_name
      content = content.gsub('{{invitation_link}}', invitation_link)
      format.text do
        render :text => content
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but when I received email that `from` is `demo@gmail.com` and that is defined in `development.rb` for configration of mailer. however I wana `email` of `from` should be `current user` means that who is inviting someone when I 
 received.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. Think about the consequences if anybody could send email using anybody else's email address! Your best option is to set the Sender's name in the `from` header while keeping your standard email address. You can set it with

```
:from => "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name} <#{from}>"
```

Basically just get the from to be formatted as `Sender's name <your@email.com>`

If you want to add a `reply-to` with the user's email address, you can pass it in as a parameter with this format:

```
:reply_to => user.email
```

To use the example you gave, it'd look like this:

```
mail(:reply_to => from, :bcc => from, :to => @user.email, :subject => subject) do |format|
```

(this assumes that you've already got the `from` param set as a default somewhere, which I believe you do)

Comment: but my boss doesn't understand and he said.
`No security concerns. Users are signing up to our service and we're sending invite emails on their behalf.`
`Lots of products do this`

Comment: Unfortunately your boss is mistaken. Ask him to give you a solid, concrete example of what he's looking for in the wild. I'm pretty certain that he won't be able to find one. Here's a site that lists your only real options when sending "on behalf" of your users: https://postmarkapp.com/support/article/846-how-can-i-send-on-behalf-of-my-users

Comment: Thanks for your great guidance. Now my boss said okay if this works only this ways so you have to make ‘reply-to’ be the senders email instead of our configure email.

Comment: Is it possible??

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to add a `reply to`. Just pass that in with your `mail(...)` method as an extra parameter.